# Read HTML files from a directory and send content of each file individually to process in a method in java spark

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

I am totally new to spark and I was trying to get all the HTML files in a directory and then pass each file's content individually (and if possible exact path also ) to another method which will process the HTML(we'll use this to extract information from that HTML) will have to do this in java only. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the sc.wholeTextFiles method to create your RDD and apply your processing logic using map transformartion on the RDD. sample code is here

```
>       JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sc);
>       JavaPairRDD<String,String> rdd = jsc.wholeTextFiles(path);
>               for(Tuple2<String, String> str : rdd.toArray()) {           System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
>           System.out.println("File name " + str._1);
>           System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
>           System.out.println();
>           System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");
>           System.out.println("content " + str._2);
>           System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");
>       }
```